# How to break line inside a Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a image and text inside a Flexbox **I want the text to be below** the image, but for some reason they just keep side-to-side.

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sizethis {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.box {
  width: 23%;
  margin: 1%;
  height: 180px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sizethis">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="myimage.png" alt="">
      <p>Item number one</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.box { flex-direction: column; }`

Comment: That will break the items alignment, the itens that have more text will be positioned above other,

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZDUM9

Comment: share all of your code then. all we can do is guess from a screenshot. seems fine here but I'm assuming you have different code https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/owJLzP

Answer (score 5):

Try to add to your '.box' class:

```
flex-direction: column;
vertical-align: top;
```

Looks like this can solve your trouble.

https://jsfiddle.net/85L0sd9o/

Comment: Then add `vertical-align: top` to your '.box'. Solved? :)

Answer (score 4):

> I want the text to be below the image, but for some reason they just keep side-to-side.

They just keep side-to-side because a flex container has the following initial settings:

- `flex-direction: row` ~ all flex items must line up horizontally
- `flex-wrap: nowrap` ~ all flex items are confined to a single line

If you want to stack items vertically, here are two methods:

1. Add `flex-direction: column` to the container. This overrides the `row` default.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 23%;
  height: 180px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sizethis">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
      <p>Item number one</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the container. This overrides the `nowrap` default. Then give each flex item enough width to push the next item to the next row.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 23%;
  height: 180px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}

p {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sizethis">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt="">
      <p>Item number one</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```